# jupyter nbconvert execute to html cron job not working

Tags: cron, jupyter, execute, nbconvert

I have this .sh to schedule in cron (ubuntu 18):

```
#!/bin/sh
wget -O x/doc1.csv  https://www.x.com
wget -O x/doc2.csv  https://www.y.com
jupyter nbconvert --execute --to html x/notebook.ipynb
```

The first two lines runs perfectly but the jupyter line does not. If I execute the .sh directly with ./ in the terminal, it performs well. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just add the path to the command and it worked:

```
#!/bin/sh
wget -O x/doc1.csv  https://www.x.com
wget -O x/doc2.csv  https://www.y.com
/home/pakin/anaconda3/bin/jupyter nbconvert --execute --to html 
x/notebook.ipynb
```